# WordPress - How can I grab the post ID for use in add_rewrite_rule

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to grab the ID of the current post, so that I can place it correctly within the rewritten URL.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {

    global $post;
    add_rewrite_tag('%type%', '([^&]+)');

    $path = 'index.php?p=' . $post->ID . ''; // This returns NULL so doesn't work.
    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?', $path, 'top' );

    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=10&type=$matches[1]', 'top' );

}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 1);
```

Basically, I have a section, where I list posts called latest, which is then filtered by a 'type' variable (the second param, like 'opinion').

`/latest/opinion/` (successfully loads posts tagged as opinion).

`/latest/opinion/my-actual-post/` (shows blank page, because `$post` is `NULL`)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps, using the `get_page_by_path()` Function could do the trick for you.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    $slug           = basename(rtrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/"));
    $pagePath       = get_page_by_path($slug);
    $page_id        = $pagePath->ID;
    global $post;
    add_rewrite_tag('%type%', '([^&]+)');

    $path = 'index.php?p=' . $page_id . ''; // This returns NULL so doesn't work.
    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?', $path, 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=10&type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out - hopefully it will help someone else.

You can use the `name` query var and match that against the last part in the URL, without needing to know the posts ID:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%type%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%name%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule('^latest/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=10&type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 1);
```

First WP will try to match three parts `/latest/opinion/something-else/`, if it doesn't have three parts then it will try to match two parts `/latest/opinion/`.

In the latter case, the `page_id` is hard coded, but in the first case, we use `name=$matches[2]` which successfully gets the dynamic post we need, without having to manually fetch any ID.

The reason the latter is hard coded to an ID, it because it is a page that gets all posts tagged with 'opinion' and not an actual post itself.

Answer (score -1):

Is this function called within the loop?

Have you tried: `get_the_id();`

That should return the current post id.  Especially with a global $post.  It looks like they are calling:
`$post = get_post();` before they attempt to pull $post->ID.  My guess is even with a global $post is an empty shell object until you set it.  Please let me know if this works on your site, I can adjust if it doesn't - it works fine for me.

Comment: These WP functions don't appear accessible from within this part.

Comment: If you installed Wordpress on your server document root, try adding
`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-load.php");` to the top of your function, near your $global.  See if that helps.

Comment: Also might be useful to read:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website .  Hope this all helps!  Cheers!

Comment: I'm afraid loading the wp-load.php doesn't work either. This is an odd one.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Sorry I tried!! :)  What a weird bug.

Comment: Haha thanks. It is an odd edge case, so was very difficult to explain well enough. All the best.